# insert and edit in mysql rows from a file with bash

Tags: mysql, sql, database, bash, sh

i am using bash to load a file in mysql, and i have:

```
mysql --local-infile=1 -u user data_base_1 < file.sql
```

and file.sql is :

```
..$ cat file.sql
 load data local infile '/folder/load.csv' into table table_1 fields terminated by '|'
```

The code works fine.

The problem is that if the PK of one row in the file exist, the row is not inserted, and i need if the row exist insert and replace the row in the table.  How can i do it?

Who can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `REPLACE` with `LOAD DATA`:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/folder/load.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE table_1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
```

Or else use the `mysqlimport --replace` option.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlimport.html#option_mysqlimport_replace

Answer (score 0):

You could load into a temporary table and then execute two SQL statements:

```
UPDATE table
 WHERE ... (match found)
;
INSERT into table(...)
SELECT ...
  FROM temp_table
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(...)
```